# VBA Macro to group and report averages by team

Tags: excel, vba

I have a weekly report I need to run where I get a list of users associated with different teams and the completion time for each of their given tasks. I need to report back each teams average cycle time for task completion.

```
task    Name    Team    Cycle time
7701    john    A            5
7825    tom     A            2
6945    terri   C            7
7036    jane    B            6
6946    tim     B            9
6899    john    A            4
7135    jim     C            6
7805    jim     C            2
9405    terri   C            8
6209    jason   B            2
7508    derek   A            4
8305    derek   A            5
8426    jane    B            6
3256    juan    C            7
```

The number of tasks, people, and teams will be dynamic

My thought is to somehow unstack the data by teams then get average cycle times from there, but I'm not sure how to achieves that. Does anyone know a VBA command for unstacking the data?

Thank you for any ideas you all may have.

Comment: `=averageif(C:C, "A", D:D)` should do the trick for Team A. Just get a distinct list of teams, change "A" to whatever cell holds the team letter you are averaging, and then copy down your formula to get all the teams covered.

Comment: Pivot Table will do it.

Comment: please post your code so far, in order to focus on what's not working, instead of creating an entire solution for you.

Comment: I'd go with what JNevill and ScottCraner commented. Don't use macro for something you can do by a reasonably simple formula or a Pivot.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub macro1()
Dim lastRow As Long, lastRow2 As Long, myArray() As Variant, longNum As Long
Dim total As Long, rowNumb As Long, tallyCount As Long

'**************************************************************************
'   This macro uses arrays because it is quicker than ranges
'   However it does paste an array to an out of the way place at columns(zw to zz)
'   I did this to incorporate a speedy removeduplicates so we would have
'   a single list of names

'   Then it siphons through the arrays to get totals for each member and
'   their averages.
'
'   It assumes your data is in columns a through d and puts
'   Memebr Name in Column E
'   Member total in column F
'   Member Average in column G

lastRow = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
myArray = Range("A1:D" & lastRow)
Range("ZW1:ZZ" & lastRow) = myArray
Columns(Range("ZX" & 1).Column).Select
Range("ZX1:ZX" & lastRow).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1), Header:=xlYes
lastRow2 = Range("ZX65536").End(xlUp).Row
nameArray = Range("ZX2:ZX" & lastRow2)
Range("ZW1:ZZ" & lastRow).ClearContents
Range("A1").Select
rowNumb = 2
For i = LBound(nameArray) To UBound(nameArray)
    Debug.Print nameArray(i, 1)
Next i

For i = LBound(nameArray) To UBound(nameArray)
    total = 0
    For j = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)
        If myArray(j, 2) = nameArray(i, 1) Then
            tallyCount = tallyCount + 1
            total = total + myArray(j, 4)
        End If
    Next j
        If total <> 0 Then
            Range("E" & rowNumb) = nameArray(i, 1)
            Range("F" & rowNumb) = total
            Range("G" & rowNumb) = total / tallyCount
            rowNumb = rowNumb + 1
            tallyCount = 0
        End If
Next i
End Sub
```